# Collecting data from NSArrays, Featuring Inexplicable Behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I have an array of objects in my Cocoa project. If the objects have an attribute that matches the passed-in value, then the object should be saved to a new array, which is the return value of the method. This seems really straight-forward, but I'm seeing some strange behaviour. Here's the method:

```
- (NSMutableArray*)tagAttributeRectsForID:(NSString*)nodeID
{
    NSMutableArray * resultArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSDictionary * line in self.lineInfoForTap) {

        NSMutableArray * glyphRects = [line valueForKey:@"GlyphRects"];

        for (NSDictionary * rectDict in glyphRects) {
            if ([rectDict valueForKey:nodeID]) {
                CGRect thisRect = CGRectFromString([rectDict valueForKey:nodeID]);
                if (thisRect.size.width > 0) {
                    [resultArray addObject:NSStringFromCGRect(thisRect)];
                }

            }
        }
        glyphRects = nil;
    }
    return resultArray;
}
```

What happens is, depending on the number of line objects that result in a set of matches, that's how many times I get the complete set of results in the returning array. In other words, I would expect a specimen result to look like this:

```
2013-04-16 19:38:37.665 Vorpal[18523:c07] (
"{{0, 486.5}, {38.44, 13.5}}",
"{{100, 486.5}, {27.12, 13.5}}",
"{{140, 483.34}, {86.54, 16.66}}",
"{{0, 508.86}, {58.62, 14.14}}"
)
```

But instead I get this:

```
2013-04-16 19:38:37.665 Vorpal[18523:c07] (
"{{0, 486.5}, {38.44, 13.5}}",
"{{100, 486.5}, {27.12, 13.5}}",
"{{140, 483.34}, {86.54, 16.66}}",
"{{0, 508.86}, {58.62, 14.14}}",
"{{0, 486.5}, {38.44, 13.5}}",
"{{100, 486.5}, {27.12, 13.5}}",
"{{140, 483.34}, {86.54, 16.66}}",
"{{0, 508.86}, {58.62, 14.14}}"
)
```

If there were three lines' worth of matching results, I will get back three sets of the data.

I can't help but think I'm missing something very basic about the way I've coded this method, but after hours of staring at it, I'm ready to throw in the towel and ask a friend. Are you that friend, anonymous SO reader? I could use a friend. :-(

Comment: This line: `for (NSDictionary * line in self.lineInfoForTap) {` iterates over your results-copying loop for each line, and if it contains a matching nodeID, adds it to the results. That seems to be why it produces X lines, but I'm not sure how this differs from what you want (since the results values in the new line could be different). Perhaps you also meant to return resultsArray after the first set of results were added (where you set glyphRect to nil)?

Comment: I don't have a direct answer but how about logging some things (like `rectDict` maybe) whenever you add an object to your result array?  ...might give a hint.

Comment: @Phillip I've done logging, and it shows the matching glyphs being added to the array, and then running through the lines array again (assuming a two-line match) and continuing to append results.

Comment: Have you tried iterating through self.lineInfoForTap by index rather than using <b>in</b>? I'm not sure what lineInfoForTap is, but maybe something you're doing is actually muting the collection as you iterate through it.

Comment: I have confirmed the line array is getting mutated. I'll give your suggestion a shot...

Comment: Sorry Gene, that didn't help. :-(

Answer (score 4):

IF your result has duplicates (which it does), then we should infer your source data has duplicates. You can use an NSSet to filter duplicates.

You can condense this code a lot, if you have a mind to. Then you won't need to explicitly create a set.

First make a category on NSString:

```
@interface NSString (ValidStringRect)
- (BOOL)validRect { return CGRectFromString(self).size.width > 0; }
@end
```

Then replace your method with:

```
- (NSMutableArray*)tagAttributeRectsForID:(NSString*)nodeID
{
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"validRect = YES"];
    // I might have the @distinctUnionOfArrays operator at the wrong point in the keypath
    id array = [self valueForKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"lineInfoForTap.GlyphRects.@distinctUnionOfArrays.%@", nodeID]];
    return [[array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred] mutableCopy];
}
```

The key "@distinctUnionOfArrays" is an array operator, without which you would have an array of arrays. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html for more info.